# Extracting database based logs using logstash

Tags: logstash

Has anyone used logstash to collect logs from an application which logs to a database instead of a file?

How can this be done?

Also, if a production application owner refuses to install JVM (which is required for logstash agent to run).... is syslog the only way? or are there other options like a native logstash agent.

Comment: Next time, please don't ask multiple questions in the same SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the SQLite input plugin there doesn't appear to be any input plugins for pulling data from relational databases, but it would be totally possible to write one. If you're not comfortable writing a Logstash plugin in Ruby, the [exec plugin](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/exec) can run an arbitrary command at a specified interval. That would allow you to write a script that fetches all the database entries since the script was run the last time.

If you can't run the JVM-based Logstash on the servers there are other more light-weight shippers like [logstash-forwarder](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder), [NXLog](http://nxlog-ce.sourceforge.net/), and [fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/).